# Changing content with navbar Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I have a question concerning Bootstrap navbars.

I've got the following simple requirements:

1. one-page application
2. a navbar with a few links
3. when clicking on the links the divs should be changed

   ```
   <div class="collapse navbar-inverse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                   <li>
                       <a  href="#gallery1">Gallery1</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                        <a  href="#gallery2">Gallery2</a>
                   </li>
                </ul>
   </div>
   ```

I know with nav-tab you can use the different sections for different content but is there a simple way with bootstrap navbar css or do i have to user jquery to accomplish that task?